# Sum based on values in other cells

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sum

I have a table in excel like the one below

```
Date        |  Type      |  Value
----------------------------------
21/01/2012  |  Other     |  1000
22/02/2012  |  Existing  |  1000
23/01/2012  |  Existing  |  1000
24/01/2012  |  Other     |  1000
12/02/2012  |  Other     |  1000
13/02/2012  |  Existing  |  1000
16/02/2012  |  Other     |  1000
19/01/2012  |  Other     |  1000
```

I want a formula that will add up all values of existing client for each month so for example it would say 1000 for January existing and 300 for January other.

I have tried everything i know how but i can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 =SUMIFS(P2:P74,N2:N74,">="&N13,N2:N74,"<="&N43,O2:O74,"other")
```

where N13 is first and N43 is last day of the month, P is your value range and o Is column witho other /existing.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try sumifs after extracting the month from the date column